# IE .attr disabled does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I have a function that would check if the product is available overnight - but it's not working in IE. It works fine in other browsers.

```
function checkOvernight() {
    id = $_2("[name='product']").val();
    if(id.length > 0) {     
        var url="inc/pscript/checker.php";
        $_2.post(url,{checkOvernight:id},function(data){
                if(data == '0') { 
                    $_2('#overnight').attr('disabled','disabled');
                } else { 
                    $_2('#overnight').attr('disabled','');

                }
        });     
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
$_2('#overnight').attr('disabled','disabled');
$_2('#overnight').attr('disabled',true);
```

But it's not working with IE. How can I get this to work in IE and all browsers? The disable is for a < select > box, if disabled is true then the user cannot change this field, but if it is false (not disabled) then the user can change it.

Comment: Are you having problems disabling it or enabling it?

Comment: disabling it, it works fine in firefox and chrome, but does not work in IE, its for a selection/option box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having no value, try using:

```
$_2('#overnight').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I came across this same issue.  This works in IE7+, but not IE6 as far as I can tell.

Comment: You should use .prop('disabled', true/false) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242205/removeattr-not-removing-disabled-attribute-in-ie