# Javascript problems with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, disabled-input

I'm trying to disable an input with JavaScript or jQuery

```
//document.getElementById("monto").disabled=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#monto").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

The code works fine in chrome, Firefox, and some versions of IE, but doesn't work with IE 8,
also tried with Hide/show but doesn't work too.

I know the best solution is to upgrade, but my boss thinks our clients are too dumb to do that.

Comment: What version of jQuery? Try `$("#monto").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: `document.getElementById("monto").disabled=true;` looks pretty good.

Comment: 2.1.0 prop doesn't work

Comment: If you are using IE8, you need to use jQuery 1.x.  The new 2.x series only works on IE9+.

Comment: @zickno Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/D2VGY/) fiddle using jQuery 2.1.0. The input appears disabled.

Comment: I'm trying now with `document.getElementById("monto").style.display = 'none';` to hide the element, and doesn't work too

Comment: Does `monto` exist at that point?

Answer (score 1):

try this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242205/removeattr-not-removing-disabled-attribute-in-ie) from stackoverflow :)

```
var disableSelection = function(){
    $("#elementId").prop("disabled", true);    
};

var enableSelection = function(){
    $("#elementId").prop("disabled", false);
};
```